# Make Tkinter Button Transparent using png file

Tags: python, tkinter

i tried to make a transparent button using a png file with Tkinter but i couldn't. I ve also tried to do it with a Canvas or a Label. I need a way to load a png image, like an arrow for example, and do something when i press it.
This is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import cv2
import Image, ImageTk
class AppButton(Label):

def __init__(self,father,imagename):
    Label.__init__(self,father,width=buttonwidth,height=buttonheight,bd=0)

    orig = Image.open(imagename)
    resized = orig.resize((buttonwidth,buttonheight),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.imagetkicon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
    self.config(image=self.imagetkicon)
    self.bind('<Button-1>',callbackmethod)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What you mean you couldnt? Any errors? Anyway, I think that in Tkinter there is no transparency.

Comment: Why are you deriving from Label when you want a Button?  How do you plan to test transparency?  (The code above will not do it.)

Comment: I want to put a label or button without the background color from the label/button. I tried with a label because i don't want the button effect.